# Swagger/Swashbuckle .Net 4.5 C# - Dynamic Object not listing

Tags: c#, .net, swagger, swashbuckle

I got a doubt of how to list the properties of the object parameter and the return object too. My sample code looks something like this. The swagger UI lists the properties of "Credentials" but not of "RequestData" being a JObject. Is there a way to list the dynamic properties?

```
public abstract class BaseController : ApiController
{
}

public class MyController : BaseController
{
    [Route("api/BusinessController/SaveBills")]
    [HttpPost]
    public APIResponse SaveBills([FromBody]APICaller value)
    {
        APIResponse response = null;
        StatusReturn statusReturn = null;
        using (BLBusiness bL = new BLBusiness())
        {
            response = bL.SaveBills(value);
        }
        return response;
        }
}

[DataContract]
public abstract class VirtualBase : IDisposable
{
}
[DataContract]
public class APICaller : VirtualBase
{
    [DataMember]
    public BasicCredentials Credentials { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public JObject RequestData { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class APIResponse : VirtualBase
{
    [DataMember]
    public StatusReturn StatusReturn { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public JObject ResponseData { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class BasicCredentials : VirtualBase
{
        public string UserId {get;set;}
}

public class Bill
{
    [DataMember]
    public string InvoiceNumber { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
        public double Amount  { get; set; }
    public List <BillDetails> Items {get;set;}
}

public class BillItemDetails
{
    [DataMember]
    public long StockID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double Quantity { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double Price { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public double TotalAmount { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: No. Not automatically. The swagger definition is generated _separately_ of potential data. Only the metadata is used. Manual ‘soft’ annotations or notes could be added.

Comment: It might be more productive to separate out generalized forms this data might be into strongly typed DTOs. Except for very specific cases, eg. proxies or documents, I recommend to avoid taking in “any structure” if it can be strongly codified.

Comment: Also make sure to only include relevant code/structures to minimally show or reproduce the issue..

Comment: Posted full sample so as to avoid confusion and to make it clear what i'm trying to achieve. Sorry, if was too big

Comment: Why use `JObject`? would not make more sense to define it ?

Comment: The API calls are standard across. The POST contains the same object for all methods and which contains 2 objects, one containing the key/token etc and the other one - the RequestData changes with the functionality. Same pattern is followed for response too